# Is it safe to connect headphone output to microphone input of a sound card?

Tags: connector

My sound card has a Stereo Mic 3.5mm TRS input. Is it safe to connect to it the headphone output, e.g. from a phone? It looks like it would work, with a 3.5mm to 3.5mm AUX type cable.
[image: E-MU Tracker Pre USB external sound card; rear view]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it probably will not give good sound as the signal might be too strong. If it works simply be aware of the risk for clipping of the sound. I would presser a special cable and connect using 6.5 mm TRS.

Do NOT connect to XLR as you might by mistake enable 48V phantom which might be detrimental to the phone. Use the inner 6.5 mm input.

The phone has a TRRS connector used for: left out, right out, mic, ground.

The sound card has TRS connector used for one channel: plus, minus, ground. If you connect a standard headphone cable, you will get distorted sound.

The cable to search for is “3.5 stereo to 1/4 mono”, sometimes called a splitter cable.